# How to check if pop up is displayed on page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute a function but only if a pop up is displayed or not. I've used Chrome Dev Tools to find the pop up element:

```
<div class="modal large popup is-visible" id="verifyIdentity" data-overlay-name="verify-identity">
```

When I close the pop-up, this changes to the below, with the words `is-visible` disappearing.

```
<div class="modal large popup" id="verifyIdentity" data-overlay-name="verify-identity">
```

I have tried the following:

```
if ($("#modal large popup").is(':visible')) { // do something }
```

```
if ($("verifyIdentity").hasClass('.modal large popup is-visible')) { // do something }
```

```
if ($(".parentClass").hasClass('.modal large popup is-visible')) { // do something }
```

None of these work and I am struggling to work out how to get my code to recognise that the pop-up is visible/not visible.

I'm new to JQuery and Javascript - can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: `if ($("#verifyIdentity").hasClass('is-visible')) { // do something }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `#` inside your selector.
This one should work properly

```
<button id="verifyBtn" onclick="verify()"> Verify </button>


function verify(){
  if ($("#verifyIdentity").hasClass('is-visible')) {  }
  console.log("works");
}
```

Check with `console.log("works");` if the function is executed properly.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jbadminton but unfortunately this isn't working still :(

Comment: @Jordan1993 can you check with `console.log()`

Comment: Thanks @Jbadminton - this is what I had been doing to check it and it was not writing to the console and hasn't worked, unfortunately!

Comment: @Jordan1993 try my answer with the function verify and also check the console for any errors

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid @Jbadminton - thank you though. If I figure it out I will let you know what the problem is

Comment: @Jordan1993 try `hasClass('is-visible')`.. dot has been removed from the class name

Answer (score 2):

Your has class approach is probably best here, however in the 'selector' for that example you're missing the actual 'ID' selector. Try:

```
if ($("#verifyIdentity").hasClass('is-visible')) { // do something }
```

You can also just target the is-visible, the rest we don't care about.

> [**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)
> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given
>   class.

Comment: Thanks so much @InchHigh but unfortunately this isn't working still :(

Comment: You're welcome. Are you running this in an event handler? Such as an onClick? Could you provide your code so we have something to look into?

Comment: Hi @InchHigh - yes I am running inside an onClick. In some instances this pop-up should show when screen loads but in some it is triggered by a click event:

`$(document).on("click", "#verifyBtn", function () { // then I have put your code here `

Comment: @Jordan1993 then your code is not being invoked at all or does has some errors.. you will need to check your browser console.

Comment: @Jordan1993 - Why is your click handler targetting 'document'? Your .on("click") doesn't look correct to me. Try: $("#verifyBtn").on("click", function () {}). If you want to wait for the doc to load, before attaching the click handler, use $(document).ready(function () { $("verifyBtn").on("click", function () {})})   - Syntax might not be perfect here as its hard to tell within a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jQuery so can offer no real help there but you ought to be able to do this using the `IntersectionObserver` API. If you click the button it will assign a class to the modal which I hope will emulate the modal becoming visible. The `output` element will be updated as a result because the IntersectionObserver callback has determined that it is visible.

```js
const out=document.querySelector('output');

const iocallback=function( entries, observer ){
  entries.forEach( e=>{
    if( e.isIntersecting && e.intersectionRatio > 0 ) {
      out.textContent='isVisible='+e.isVisible;
    } else {
      out.textContent='isVisible='+e.isVisible;
    }
  });
}

let modal=document.getElementById( 'verifyIdentity' );
let options={
  root:null,
  rootMargin:'0px',
  threshold:1,
  delay:100,
  trackVisibility:true
};
let io=new IntersectionObserver( iocallback, options );
  io.observe( modal );

document.querySelector('[type="button"]').onclick=(e)=>{
  modal.classList.toggle('visible');
};
```

```css
body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;margin:1rem;padding:1rem}
#verifyIdentity{ display:none; border:1px solid red; }
.visible{display:block!important;}
output{border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id='verifyIdentity'> #modal# </div>
  <output></output>
  <input type='button' value='Toggle visibility' />
```